# Difference in AspNetCore identity 2.0 and 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

- What is the difference in AddIdentity and AddDefaultIdentity

**ConfigureServices Method in Startup from AspNetCore identity 2.0**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**ConfigureServices Method in Startup from AspNetCore identity 2.1**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1884

Answer (score 0):

[AddDefaultIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs#L47-L63) was introduced in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Calling AddDefaultIdentity is similar to calling the following:

1. AddIdentity
2. AddDefaultUI
3. AddDefaultTokenProviders

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8434